# Jquery creating checkboxs dynamically, and finding checked boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have information that comes out of a database and gets put into a list with a checkbox by each element. This is how it is currently done:

```
  function subjects(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "lib/search/search.subject.php",
    async: "false",
    success: function(response){
    alert(response);
            var responseArray = response.split(',');    
            for(var x=0;x<responseArray.length;x++){
            $("#subjects").append("<br />");
            $("#subjects").append(responseArray[x]);
            $("#subjects").append("<input type='checkbox' />");
            }           
        }
    });
}
```

it works fine, but I need a way to pick up on if a checkbox is clicked, and if it is clicked then display which one was clicked, or if multiple ones are clicked.

I can't seem to find a way to pick up on the checkboxs at all.

the response variable is "math,science,technology,engineering"

Comment: Look into jQuery's `.on()` function.

Comment: Can you specify what's return in your response ?

Comment: response = math,science,technology,engineering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are populating the Checkboxes Dynamically you need to **Delegate the event**

```
$("#subjects").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
       alert('Checkbox checked')
    }
});
```

To better capture the data it is better if you encase the corresponding data into a span , so that it can be easier to search..

```
 $("#subjects").append('<span>'+responseArray[x] + '</span>');
```

---

```
$("#subjects").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if( $this.is(":checked") ) {
            var data = $this.prev('span').html();
            alert('Current checkbox is : '+ data ) 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to give your dynamically injected checkboxes a class to target them better, but based on your code try:

```
$("#subjects").on("click", "input", function() {
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
    // do something
    }
});
```

Since your input elements are added dynamically, you need to use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to bind the click event to them. In your case you need to use `.on()` to bind to an element that exist in the DOM when the script is loaded. In your case, the element with the ID #subjects.

This note from the docs is mainly for machineghost who downvoted my answer for no apparent reason:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#subjects input[type=checkbox]').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

or the change event: in case someone uses a keyboard

```
$('#subjects input[type=checkbox]').on('change',function(){
    alert($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

simple fiddle example:http://jsfiddle.net/Dr8k8/

to get the array example use the index of the inputs

```
alert($(this).prop('checked') +'is'+ $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').index(this)+ responseArray[$(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').index(this) ]);
```

simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dr8k8/1/

EDIT: Just for an example, you could put the results in an array of all checked boxes and do somthing with that:

```
$('#subjects>input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var checklist = [];
    $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', "lime");
        var myindex = $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').index(this);
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
            checklist[myindex] = responseArray[myindex];
        }
    });
    $('#currentlyChecked').text(checklist);
});
```

EDIT2:

I thought about this a bit and you can improve it by using .data() and query that or store it based on an event (my button called out by its id of "whatschecked")

```
var responseArray = ['math', 'science', 'technology', 'engineering'];// just for an example
var myList = '#subjects>input[type=checkbox]';//to reuse
for (var x = 0; x < responseArray.length; x++) {
    // here we insert it all so we do not hit the DOM so many times
    var iam = "<br />" + responseArray[x] + "<input type='checkbox' />";
    $("#subjects").append(iam);
    $(myList).last().data('subject', responseArray[x]);// add the data
}
var checklist = [];// holds most recent list set by change event
$(myList).on('change', function() {
    checklist = [];
    $(myList).each(function() {
        var myindex = $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').index(this);
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
            checklist.push($(this).data('subject'));
            alert('This one is checked:' + $(this).data('subject'));
        }
    });
});
// query the list we stored, but could query the checked list data() as well, see the .each() in the event handler for that example
$("#whatschecked").click(function() {
    var numberChecked = checklist.length;
    var x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < numberChecked; x++) {
        alert("Number " + x + " is " + checklist[x] + " of " + numberChecked);
    }
});
```

live example of last one: http://jsfiddle.net/Dr8k8/5/

Answer (score -1):

The general pattern to do something when a checkbox input is clicked is:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    // Do something
})
```

The general pattern to check whether a checkbox input is checked or not is:

```
var isItChecked = $('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked');
```

In your particular case you'd probably want to do something like:

```
$('#subjects input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
```

to limit the checkboxes involved to the ones inside your `#subjects` element.

Comment: This won't work if the input fields don't exist when the page loads.

Comment: Umm, obviously, but that had nothing to do with the question.  The author asked " I need a way to pick up on if a checkbox is clicked, and if it is clicked then display which one was clicked, or if multiple ones are clicked."  I provided both a way of detecting clicks and a way of checked for clicked (checked) status.

Comment: However you code won't work based on the OP's code. Obviously.

Comment: What are you talking about?  My code is just generic jQuery code; it is 100% applicable to the OP.

Comment: You should probably brush up on how dynamically added elements need to be bound to events when using jQuery.

Comment: Again, what are you talking about?  That has nothing to do with my answer.  You seem to be imagining that the author is (for no good reason) inserting the code I wrote before appending elements to the page.